# When should we use ForeignKey and ManyToOne in django

Tags: database, django, database-design, django-models

There are two models College, Department

```
class College(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    uid = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
    website = models.URLField()

class Dept(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    uid = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    college = models.ForeignKey(College)
```

Here, we can say in the relationship in two ways...

1. Each College has many departments
2. Each department belongs to a College (the above model belongs to)

Trouble when using 2nd design

*Each department in college can't have duplicate names*.. i.e, we can't have multiple departments in a college under one single name.. how to do that?

Did employ right db design? If not how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Your model with foreign key looks like right if there cannot be a department divided into many colleges. If a department can be divided into a many colleges, you'll have to set a ManyToMany with a "through" argument, and in the trough model add a "unique_together" like bellow:

For the FK, to add your constraint, you should change Dept as follows:

```
class Dept(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    uid = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    college = models.ForeignKey(College)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('name', 'college'),)
```

Comment: The "unique_together" adds a Django constraint to avoid 2 Depts with same name and college, and also adds the constraint in the database. Take care you cannot directly set a many to many attribute as argument of unique_together. More details here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together